# Please recommend an XML traffic capture and web debugging tool

Tags: networking

I've found myself in dire need of a web traffic capture tool (specifically for XML debugging). I was using Fiddler on Windows, but I don't know what to use in Ubuntu.

Comment: What is an XML transmitter?

Answer (score 2):

You say "Fiddler" but then link to a "comparison of packet analyzers".

If it is just packet analysis you need, wireshark is the only one I've used, heard, or seen written about. If you need the "man in the middle" packet alteration of Fiddler, I can't advise you.

Comment: The thread [Linux-alternative to Fiddler2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040642/linux-alternative-to-fiddler2) might be usefull as well.

Comment: [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=446758) thread from Ubuntu Forums seems to be nice. A brief starting point may be: [Getting started with Wireshark, the Fiddler for Ubuntu](http://www.tohir.co.za/2010/02/01/getting-started-with-wireshark-the-fiddler-for-ubuntu/)